# use of unassigned local variable error on IDbconnection for DataContext .?

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

```
IDbConnection donn;
string dstr = "Server=.;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=sspi";
donn.ConnectionString = dstr.ToString();

DataContext context = new DataContext(donn);
```

Find the above code snippet- donn variable is for IDbConnection and i couldn't set the property `ConnectionString` of it. In that line (3rd line) it shows an error that -

```
 'Use of unassigned local variable 'donn''
```

Please help..

Comment: Well - the error message says exactly what the problem is: You didn't assign a value to donn. You just declared it. You are missing the part with the `new`.

Comment: Interface and Abstract classes never initialize using NEW

Comment: That's why I haven't provided a sample code - I don't know which concrete `IDbConnection` implementation you are using.

Comment: yes i got the problem - IDbConnection should be initialized with the DataProvoder or with the connection class of the data provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`donn` is declared, but it isn't assigned any value.

Try something like:

```
IDBConnection donn = new SqlConnection(dstr);
```